# Volley does not work correctly when URL has UTF-8 on Android version less than 5

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I use the volley library in my app, and I accidentally realized that my String URL for Android less than 5, the response from the server is empty, But in the higher version the answer is correct, So I checked My URL, Which is as follows:

```
string url ====> http://www.articler.ir/android_php/search.php?Method=rate&CAT=مهندسی%20عمران
```

Part of this has a character of UTF-8, Why this URL returns the correct response in higher versions of Android (5+). But the response is empty in the lower versions(5-)?

Please help me, thank You...

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        final ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.test);

        final CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,  myList);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        FirstURL = intent.getStringExtra("SearchURL");
        SearchURL = FirstURL.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

        Log.d("Search", "Search: " + SearchURL);
        myList.removeAll(myList);


       JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(SearchURL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

               Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               Log.d("VolleyRes", "response: " + response);

               for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                   try {

                       JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                       Model model = new Model();
                       model.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                       model.setMainText(jsonObject.getString("mainText"));
                       model.setrate(jsonObject.getDouble("rate"));
                       model.setYear(jsonObject.getInt("year"));
                       model.setConfName(jsonObject.getString("confName"));
                       model.setProductId(jsonObject.getInt("productId"));
                       model.setCountView(jsonObject.getInt("countView"));
                       model.setPdfURL(jsonObject.getString("pdfURL"));
                       // authors is json array
                       authors = new ArrayList<String>();
                       JSONArray authorArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("authors");
                       for (int j = 0; j < authorArray.length(); j++) {
                           if (!authors.contains(authorArray.getString(j)) && !authorArray.isNull(j)) {
                               authors.add((String) authorArray.get(j));
                           }
                       }
                       model.setAuthor(authors);

                       // Keywords is json array
                       keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
                       JSONArray keywordArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Keywords");
                       for (int k = 0; k < keywordArray.length(); k++) {
                           if (!keywords.contains(keywordArray.getString(k)) && !keywordArray.isNull(k)) {
                               keywords.add((String) keywordArray.get(k));
                           }
                       }
                       model.setKeywords(keywords);
                       myList.add(model);

                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
               listView.setAdapter(adapter);
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

           }

       }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

               VolleyLog.d("VolleyErr", "ErrorMassage: " + error.getMessage());
           }

       });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);






        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                int year = myList.get(position).getYear();
                int productId = myList.get(position).getProductId();
                int countView = myList.get(position).getCountView();
                double rate = myList.get(position).getrate();
                String title = myList.get(position).getTitle();
                String mainText = myList.get(position).getMainText();
                String confName = myList.get(position).getConfName();
                ArrayList authors = myList.get(position).getAuthor();
                ArrayList keywords = myList.get(position).getKeywords();
                String pdfURL = myList.get(position).getPdfURL();


                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.
                        getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putInt("productId", productId); //InputString: from the EditText
                editor.putInt("countView", countView);
                editor.putFloat("rate", (float) rate);
                editor.putString("pdfURL",pdfURL);
                editor.putString("title",title);
                editor.putString("mainText",mainText);
                editor.putString("confName",confName);
                editor.putString("authors", String.valueOf(authors));
                editor.putString("keywords", String.valueOf(keywords));
                editor.putInt("year", year);
                editor.commit();


                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetailActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        // finish();
                    }
                }, 1500);

            }
        });



    }
}
```

Comment: Post error message.

Comment: @PravinDivraniya response return :  []

`D/VolleyRes: response: []`

Comment: Are you using SSL in your app? If TLS configure on your server and if yes then pls provide version of the same.

Comment: Are you using GSON?

Comment: @PravinDivraniya I fix it ,see my answer, thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searches, I realized that URL with Persian fonts on Android less than 5 is not supported. So I need to change the string by encoding it so I used the method below to change it.

```
 //this is initial string url ====> http://www.articler.ir/android_php/search.php?Method=rate&CAT=مهندسی%20عمران

    String MyKey = مهندسی عمران;

    final String EncodeKey= URLEncoder.encode(MyKey , "UTF-8");

    String EncodeURL = " http://www.articler.ir/android_php/search.php?Method=rate&CAT= " + EncodeKey;
```

after changing this part, my response is correct, like 5+ version;